# SVG inside CSS, image shrinking

Tags: html, image, svg, resize

What would cause the resizing of an image(svg in this case) when moved from  inside the html, to its on css file. I have an image that sits over top the background, and uses an svg mask to reveal the underlying background image when the mouse hovers over part of it. This works just fine! However, when I move the css and the javascript to its own file, instead of all in the same html file, the top image(inside the svg) shrinks down to a small size. any help on why this is happening would be appreciated thanks!

this is the original which works perfectly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="mouseOverJS.js"></script>
    <style>
       svg {
            width: 856px;
            height: 856px;
        }
        body {
            background-color: white;
            background-image: url("lolMap.png");
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            margin: 0; padding:0;
        }
        image:hover {
            mask: url("#cursorMask");

        }
        p{
            margin: 0; padding:0;
        } 

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
    <svg>
        <mask id="cursorMask" maskUnits="objectBoundingBox" maskContentUtils="objectBoundingBox">
        <defs>
            <filter id="f1" x="0" y="0">
              <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="8" />
            </filter>
            <radialGradient id="grad1" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%" fx="50%" fy="50%">
              <stop offset="50%" style="stop-color:rgb(0,0,0); stop-opacity:2" />
              <stop offset="75%" style="stop-color:rgb(0,0,0); stop-opacity:1" />
              <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(0,0,0);stop-opacity:0" />
            </radialGradient>
        </defs>
        <g>
            <!-- the SECOND rect element is what determines the transparent area -->
            <rect x="0" y="0" width="856" height="856" fill="#FFFFFF" />
            <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="100" fill="url(#grad1)" />
        </g>
    </mask>
</defs>
   <image width="856" height="856" xlink:href="lolMapDark.png" />
    </svg>
    </p>
</body>
```

this is the CSS stylesheet with the same info just in its own file this time.

```
svg {
width: 856px;
height: 856px;
}

body {
background-color: white;
background-image: url("lolMap.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
margin: 0; padding:0;
}

image:hover {
mask: url("#cursorMask");


}

p{
margin: 0; padding:0;
}
```

this is the js file

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
            var img = document.getElementsByTagName("image")[0];
            var imgPos = img.getBoundingClientRect();
            var imgX = imgPos.left;
            var imgY = imgPos.top;
            var circle = document.getElementsByTagName("circle")[0];
            var circleRadius = circle.getAttribute("r") / 2;
            img.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
                 circle.setAttribute("cx", e.clientX - imgX);
                    circle.setAttribute("cy", e.clientY - imgY);
                }, false);
        }, false);
```

I also swapped out the style tags with

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mouseOverCSS.css">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at setting the 'viewbox`; sizing/resizing can generally be controlled with height/width and viewbox.

```
<svg width="856" height="856" viewbox="0 0 856 856">
```

It is also possible that the external reference is not getting applied for some reason ... check the Console/Network and Inspector; looking for errors loading in the console/network and check the element within the Inspector to see what CSS is being applied.

Reference: **http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/svg-viewport-view-box.html**

Comment: thanks rfornal. The svg viewbox seemed to work. I wasn't getting any errors in the console/network so thats why i was a little confused. any idea why that would need to be applied when the css is moved to an external file and doesn't need to when inside the same file?

Comment: Wish I could tell you ... not a clue.  I'll take a copy of all the code in both iterations and play with it sometime.  If I come up with something I'll post an update here.